# Can I set up Ubuntu on ONE partition of a multi-partitioned USB stick?

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, liveusb

I'd like to make a Live USB for Ubuntu.  In an ideal world, I would:

- Partition USB drive in two parts.
- Install Ubuntu on one part.
- Use other part for storage.

Is this possible?

Comment: Ubuntu allows you to make a Live USB without going through the regular installation procedure, allowing you to leave space for other files.
Is there a specific reason you want to partition the drive?

Comment: I thought that I couldn't save any data to the USB, besides the OS.  Are you telling me that I can create a normal Live USB and also save files to that USB drive?  If so, please explain that in an Answer, and it'll probably be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done, but is not necessary.  Ubuntu installs in an windows partition, and uses a file for persistant storage.

You can use the same partition for Windows files storage.